# How can I write to Parquet faster using java?

Tags: java, database, parquet

I'm trying to write a `Dataset` object as a Parquet file using java.

I followed [this](https://github.com/MaxNevermind/Hadoop-snippets/blob/master/src/main/java/org/maxkons/hadoop_snippets/parquet/ParquetReaderWriterWithAvro.java) example to do so but it is absurdly slow.

It takes ~1.5 minutes to write ~10mb of data, so it isn't going to scale well when I want to write hundreds of mb of data.
I did some cpu profiling and found that 99% of the time came from the **`ParquetWriter.write()`** method.

I tried increasing the page size and block size of the `ParquetWriter` but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the performance. Is there any way to make this process faster or is it just a limitation of the Parquet library?

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328393/how-to-read-and-write-parquet-files-efficiently ??

Comment: Is the 10MB the size of the resulting parquet file or the input data? Also, that example seems to first prepare all data as `List<GenericData.Record>`, are you sure the actual writing is slow or the creation of those objects?

Comment: @JörnHorstmann The ~10MB is the resulting parquet file. Serializing the `Dataset` object as a CSV results in a ~1MB file. I did some profiling with Intellij and the issue is for sure in the `.write()` method and not in the creation of the objects

Comment: Did you disable the debug logging of some of the Parquet classes?  When I did that, my speed of creating Parquet files went up by a huge factor.

Answer (score 0):

I've had reasonable luck using `org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter` to write `org.apache.parquet.example.data.Group` made by the `org.apache.parquet.example.data.simple.SimpleGroupFactory`.

https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-benchmarks/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/benchmarks/DataGenerator.java

I'd love to know of a faster way (more columns x rows per second per thread).